# Query to compare two columns in a same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to compare two columns.

The data is in a table called `test_t1` and it has 4 columns `(seq_id,client_id,client_code,emp_ref_code)`:

[image]

I need the result for all the `client_id`'s for which the `client_code` or `emp_ref_code` is different.

The expected result is:

[image]

I'm finding it difficult to do it, could anybody please help me here.

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you get errors ? Can you give us the example code *as text not screenshots* ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to count distinct [`client_code` + `emp_ref_code`] combinations per `client_id`, and then extract those that have more than a single combination.

There's a *separator* in concatenation to avoid *false positives*; choose character that doesn't appear in neither `client_code` and `emp_ref_code`.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (seq_id, client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code) as
  2    (select 1, 100, '678NB', '235/345' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 100, '678NB', '235/345' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 200, '564UH', '234/678' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 200, '432ED', '234/678' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 300, '432TG', '235/897' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 300, '432TG', '324/675' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 300, '453YH', '235/897' from dual
  9    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select client_id,
 12            count(distinct client_code||'~'||emp_ref_code) cnt
 13     from test
 14     group by client_id
 15    )
 16  select a.*
 17  from test a join temp b on a.client_id = b.client_id
 18  where b.cnt > 1
 19  order by seq_id;

    SEQ_ID  CLIENT_ID CLIEN EMP_REF
---------- ---------- ----- -------
         3        200 564UH 234/678
         4        200 432ED 234/678
         5        300 432TG 235/897
         6        300 432TG 324/675
         7        300 453YH 235/897

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Alot for your quick and valuable answer !!!

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to do with Self join ??

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `group by` and `having` :

```
select max(seq_id) as seq_id, client_id,client_code,emp_ref_code
from test
group by client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code
having count(1) = 1;
```

If you are looking for a way to ignore also the ones that are unique then try this :

```
with cte as (
  select max(seq_id) over (partition by client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code) as seq_id,
        client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code, 
        count(1) over (partition by client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code) as count_row,
        count(1) over (partition by client_id) as count_row_per_client
  from test
)
select seq_id, client_id,client_code,emp_ref_code
from cte
where count_row = 1 and COUNT_ROW_PER_CLIENT > 1
order by seq_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/to7V0hrh)

Comment: That will find a client ID with a single row, not only those with multiple codes - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PVLx2aNC) - which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants (though it's not entirely clear...).

Comment: from the fiddle you have shared I see that my query is correct, I didn't get what you have found

Comment: The single entry for client ID 400, which I added, is returned by your query. The OP seems to only want to list the rows where a client ID has multiple codes (of either type). Client 100 is excluded because it has two entries but with the same codes, the others have multiple codes. I think that's what they want anyway. By that logic my new 400 row should be excluded because that ID doesn't have multiple codes either.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got the point

Comment: I have updated my answer to take in consideration the point that have been shared by @AlexPoole

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic version of the count function to get the number of different codes for each ID, and then use that as a subquery - as a CTE or an inline view - and filter out any where both counts are 1:

```
select seq_id, client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code
from (
  select seq_id, client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code,
    count(distinct client_code) over (partition by client_id) as client_codes,
    count(distinct emp_ref_code) over (partition by client_id) as emp_ref_codes
  from test_t1
)
where client_codes > 1 or emp_ref_codes > 1
order by seq_id;
```

| SEQ_ID | CLIENT_ID | CLIENT_CODE | EMP_REF_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 200 | 564UH | 234/678 |
| 4 | 200 | 432ED | 234/678 |
| 5 | 300 | 432TG | 235/897 |
| 6 | 300 | 432TG | 324/675 |
| 7 | 300 | 453YH | 235/897 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zdlp1sol)

> Is there any way to achieve this by using self join ?

You could do an outer join and filter, but it's a bit messy:

```
select distinct t1.seq_id, t1.client_id, t1.client_code, t1.emp_ref_code
from test_t1 t1
left join test_t1 t2
on t2.client_id = t1.client_id
and (t2.client_code != t1.client_code or t2.emp_ref_code != t1.emp_ref_code)
where t2.seq_id is not null
order by t1.seq_id;
```

Or you could use `not exists` which is a bit nicer:

```
select seq_id, client_id, client_code, emp_ref_code
from test_t1 t1
where exists (
  select null
  from test_t1 t2
  where t2.client_id = t1.client_id
  and (t2.client_code != t1.client_code or t2.emp_ref_code != t1.emp_ref_code)
)
order by seq_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oRnEbNRI)

But both hit the table twice, which isn't necessary. (But still, benchmark different approaches to check what works best for your real data. Analytic functions have their own cost, so there isn't always a single 'best' way of doing things.)

Comment: Thank You so much, Its working absolutely fine

Comment: Hey, Just wondering Is there any way to achieve this by using self join ?

Comment: @Node98 - there are usually lots of ways to do things; you can outer join, or use `not exists`, but they hit the table twice - which might not matter much, particularly if it's a small table where caching makes it a bit moot. I've added examples.

Comment: HI, I was exactly doing like the 1st outer join/inner join with filter method, but with real data i am getting extra records, not sure why .... I am passing all the required condition

Comment: Did you use `distinct`? With multiple duplicates you will see the same row match against more than other, and you only want to see each of them once. (Needing to use distinct is often a sign you're doing something wrong, or could do it a better way...)